# CSS: How to get rid of space left by moved element?

Tags: css, positioning, element

I have an element that I moved right and then pushed up on top.
It's lined up perfectly, but for some reason it still leaves the space it previously occupied below it. I tried clear, overflow, whitespace, negative-margins, visibility, block, etc. No joy. CSS doesn't seem to anticipate human thought.

```
 div.overlay-ad{

     position:relative;
     width:310px;
     height:260px;
     top:-332px;
     left:538px;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.overlay-ad{
     position:absolute;
     width:310px;
     height:260px;
     top:-332px;
     left:538px;
}
```

The `position: relative` makes your block take up space in the flow. It doesn't matter that the visual rendering is then positioned away. `position: absolute` moves the block out of the general flow.